# DearPyGui in-game injection

Tags: python, code-injection, imgui, dearpygui

How can i inject DearPYGui window in game?

I stopped on this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY53r.jpg
But i need it to work in game.

Code that worked for this result:

```
import os

import subprocess

import pymem

from pymem import Pymem

 

notepad = subprocess.Popen(['dotnet.exe'])

 

pm = pymem.Pymem('dotnet.exe')

pm.inject_python_interpreter()

filepath = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\CryoFall\CryoFall Client.exe'

shellcode = """

import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

from dearpygui.demo import show_demo

show_demo()

dpg.start_dearpygui()

""".format(filepath)

pm.inject_python_shellcode(shellcode)

notepad.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must embed python on your project to achieve what you're looking for, there's no way you can attach your executable inside dearPyGui viewport, unless they share the same buffers, etc.